# fold list of tuples in scala with destructuring

Tags: scala

```
scala> val l = List((1,2), (2,3))
l: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3))
```

I can do

```
scala>  (0 /: l) {(a, i) => i._1 + a}
res20: Int = 3
```

But I want to be able to name the tuple's elements. Something like:

```
scala> (0 /: l) {(a, (b,c)) => b + a}
<console>:1: error: not a legal formal parameter
       (0 /: l) {(a, (b,c)) => b + a}
                     ^
```

I know I can do:

```
scala> (0 /: l) {(a, i) => val (b, c) = i; b + a}
res0: Int = 3
```

But is there a way of making the code more concise (my real code involves several such folds and I don't like needing to invent a variable name ('i' in the example above) for each)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
(0 /: l) { case (a, (b, c)) => b + a }
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that, in addition to Walter's answer, you can use the underscore `_` instead of `c` in the pattern match:

```
val i = (0 /: l) { case (a, (b, _)) => b + a }
```

It acts as an *anything goes* placeholder in the `Tuple2` pattern and (to my mind) makes it clearer that you don't actually use the value in your calculation.

Also, in **2.8** you would be able to do:

```
val i = l.map(_._1).sum
```