# fold that produces a tuple (avoiding multiple traversals of the input)

Tags: scala, fold

I have a list and want to use this to produce three lists. I can do this with two applications of filter:

```
val z_out = zs.filter(p1)
val z_in = zs.filter(p2)
val z_split = zs.diff(z_out union z_in)
```

Can I do this with one traversal of the list? As in:

```
val (z_out, z_in, z_split) = zs.foldLeft(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, as long as the result of fold is a tuple:

```
scala> val (a,b,c) = Nil.foldLeft((1,2,3))((x,y) => x)
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
c: Int = 3
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701001/fold-list-of-tuples-in-scala-with-destructuring?rq=1

Comment: @SergeyPassichenko, the question you pointed is about using tuples in the fold arguments not in the return.

Comment: jaybee asked about it, but delete comment later :)