# Scala fold on a Sequence of a Tuple

Tags: scala

I have the following method that I would like to apply fold operation on:

```
def rec(id: String, elems: Seq[(String, MyCase)]) = {
  elems.fold(Seq.empty[(String, Seq[String])] { elem =>
    ....
  }
}
```

What I do not get is the type of the elem is Nothing and I do not understand why it should be! Any clues?

Comment: I don't see a `fold` function on [Tuple2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Tuple2).

Comment: What is the type of `MyCase`?

Comment: Yeah the title is misleading.

Its a fold on a sequence of tuples.

Comment: I have adjusted the title but the content still holds.

Comment: Following the other comments, please post a [MCVE] of your problem so we can easily reconstruct the issue locally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fold list of tuples in scala with destructuring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701001/fold-list-of-tuples-in-scala-with-destructuring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing parentheses before the `{`, that's why your IDE, probably, thinks, the type is `Nothing`.

Also, you are, probably, looking for `foldLeft`, not `fold` (the first parameter of the latter must match the type of elements of the sequence).

Now the (simplified) signature of `.foldLeft` on `Seq[A]` is:

```
   foldLeft[B](b: B)(f: (B,A) => B)
```

As you can see, it takes a function, that transforms a `Tuple2` into the type of the first parameter. The first element of the tuple has the same type as the first param, the second element is the same type as the elements of the sequence.

In your example, `B` is `Seq[(String, Seq[String])]`, and the sequence elements are `(String, MyCase)`. The type of input to the function would therefore take a horribly looking tuple like this:

```
(Seq[(String, Seq[String])], (String, MyCase))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by you are not only want to `fold`, you also you want to `map` the **tuple**, see the fold method signature:

```
  def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1 = foldLeft(z)(op)
```

The input type and outtype must be same: `A1`,

so if want to map, you maybe want to try `foldLeft`:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B =
```

There is a generics for output type `B` without bounding to `A`.

also we can find the `fold` source code is calling:

```
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1 = foldLeft(z)(op)
```

use `foldLeft` maybe like:

```
elements.fold(Seq.empty[(String, Seq[String])])((a, b) => a ++ Seq((b._1, Seq[String]())))
```

Answer (score 0):

2nd EDIT: 
I'm an idiot. A fold must return the same value as the input type.
Replace all the below folds with foldLefts for example and it works.
You can't transform the data type in a standard fold.
It was compiling for me but I didn't notice the return type was useless.

The second parameter in a fold is a function:

```
(ResultType, SingleElement) => Result Type
```

In this case

```
(Seq[(String, Seq[String])], Seq[(String, MyCase)]) => Seq[(String, Seq[String])]
```

Your code only has one input on the second parameter so the compiler doesn't know what it is. So it should look something like:

```
elems.foldLeft(Seq.empty[(String, Seq[MyCase])] {(zeroSeq, nextElem) =>
     //zeroSeq: Seq.empty[(String, Seq[MyCase]
     //nextElem: (String, MyCase)
}
```

EDIT:

The following for example compiles:

```
case class MyCase(x: String)
val elems: Seq[(String, MyCase)] = Seq(("Hi", MyCase("B")))

elems.foldLeft(Seq.empty[(String, Seq[MyCase])]){(z, s) =>
    z
}
```

Comment: Nope! This does not even compile!

Comment: Still not! the type of z and s is Equals instaed of what I'm expecting!

Comment: Try qualifying z and s with the actual types and you will see that it does not compile!

Comment: s: String and z: Seq[String] fails compilation

Comment: I don't appreciate you yelling.

Also at this point you're going to have to listen to the comments on your question and add more detail. I'm not sure what more anyone can do.

Comment: Relax! I did not yell! I was just saying that it does not compile! Even before I posted this question, I tried already what you have posted. It makes little sense to post something that does not compile as an answer.

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to help me out! Thanks!

Comment: @sparkr, your example doesn't compile either.  You are missing (at the least) a closing paren for the fold invocation.  As was requested, please provide a minimal, executable sample.

Comment: Yes! That was why I had to post this question here. If it was executable then  there very little need for me to ask for help!